# Can I post without navigating to a new page in a WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, post, webbrowser-control

If we use

```
this.webBrowser1.Navigate("Website", "_self", "Data", "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

the data will post when `webBrowser1` is navigating to the website. The problem is there, can I post the data with `webBrowser1` when the website is load complete and don't let the `webBrowser1` navigate the website again?

Comment: Why not use an `HttpWebRequest` instead ?

Comment: It will keep the webbrowser cookie?

Answer (score 1):

You can do so via JavaScript with something like jQuery's $.post(..) to avoid reloading the page with the target results.

Comment: Can you Give me an example? I really don't understand .

Comment: C# is a server-side language. Whereas what yo're asking is mainly considered client-side. It doesn't have anything to do with C#.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to post data use the "axwebbrowser"